# How do I print my an array in a toString() method?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I'm trying to print an array via toString() so I can call it to another method. What exactly am I doing wrong? Why isn't it compiling and what is a better solution.

```
public class Applicants
{
    private String applicant[];
    public Applicants()
{
    Application student1 = new Application()
    Application student2 = new Application()
    Application student3 = new Application()
    Application student4 = new Application()
    Application student5 = new Application()
    Application student6 = new Application();

    Application applicant[] = new Application[5];
    applicant[0] = student1;
    applicant[1] = student2;
    applicant[2] = student3;
    applicant[3] = student4;
    applicant[4] = student5;
    applicant[5] = student6;

    for (int index = 0; index < applicant.length; index++)
    {   
         System.out.println(applicant[index]);
    }

}
public String toString(String[] applicant)
{
    String output = new String();
    String total;
    for (int index = 0; index < applicant.length; index++)
    {
        total = System.out.println(applicant[index]);
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: It doesn't compile because this isn't nearly valid code: `total = System.out.println(applicant[index]);`

Comment: You're shadowing your field variable `applicant` with a completely different type...that's just awkward.

Comment: Are you trying to override `toString()`? They need to have the same parameters in order to do that.

Comment: When something isn't compiling the compiler will give you hints as to what lines the code is wrong on. By not supplying that information you are asking others to debug your code with even less information than you have available to you. Do you think that is fair and reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

There are three things *wrong*, and one "hey, pay attention".

1. **You are shadowing your field `applicant` inside of your constructor.**  What this means is when you're done with your constructor, your `String[]` is `null`.  Not full of `null`, just `null`.

   What you probably meant to do was declare `private Application[] applicant` as your field, then not redeclare it inside of your constructor.
2. **`total = System.out.println(applicant[index]);` is not a valid statement.**  You cannot assign the result of a `void` method to anything.  You have it right in your constructor, so it's surprising that you didn't get it correct down here.
3. **`toString` does not take any arguments.**  Use your field.
4. **Please have `toString` defined on your `Application` object, as that will make your life easier.  Otherwise, extract meaningful information from that object.**  You're going to do some string concatenation on this one in either event, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the toString method in the Application class:

```
public class Application {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       // your code here
    }
 }
```

Note the use of the Override annotation. This will make the compiler check that you are actually overriding the method you say you are - in your current code, you are not as toString does not take any parameters.

As for implementation of toString, I would go with Google Guava

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this.getClass()).add(..).add(..).toString();
 }
```

See here for more info: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained

[Guava docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html)